# How to catch the special ServiceStack exceptions "response.FlushAsync()" from ServiceStack.HttpResponseExtensionsInternal?

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack

The inner exception is "The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x80070057."

They only happen in the product environment, it's not my code, so `try catch` can not help.

The **UncaughtExceptionHandlers** also can not catch it:

```
 UncaughtExceptionHandlers.Add((req, res, operationName, ex) => {
                if (ex is HttpException && ex.Message.StartsWith("The remote host closed the connection", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) {
                    res.EndRequest(true); 
                }
            });
```

The stack trace:

```
   at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.RaiseCommunicationError(Int32 result, Boolean throwOnDisconnect)
   at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.ExplicitFlush()
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush(Boolean finalFlush, Boolean async)
   at System.Web.HttpWriter.WriteFromStream(Byte[] data, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.IO.Stream.<>c.<BeginWriteInternal>b__46_0(Object )
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at System.IO.Stream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.IO.Stream.<>c.<BeginEndWriteAsync>b__53_1(Stream stream, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncTrimPromise`1.Complete(TInstance thisRef, Func`3 endMethod, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at ServiceStack.StreamExtensions.<WriteToAsync>d__39.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at ServiceStack.BufferedExtensions.<FlushBufferIfAnyAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at ServiceStack.Host.AspNet.AspNetResponse.<FlushAsync>d__40.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at ServiceStack.HttpResponseExtensionsInternal.<WriteToResponse>d__7.MoveNext()
```

- loggerName: ServiceStack.HttpResponseExtensionsInternal
- ServiceStack version: 5.7.0
- Net Framework: 4.7.2

It happens too many times, so I want to ignore it.
How could do the trick with the internal async exception process?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to filter out the error messages from `ServiceStack.HttpResponseExtensionsInternal` Type in your current logger implementation.